# How do I create a persistent volume claim with ReadWriteMany in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

What is the best way to create a persistent volume claim with ReadWriteMany attaching the volume to multiple pods?

Based off the support table in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes, GCEPersistentDisk does not support ReadWriteMany natively.

What is the best approach when working in the GCP GKE world? Should I be using a clustered file system such as CephFS or Glusterfs? Are there recommendations on what I should be using that is production ready?

I was able to get an NFS pod deployment configured following the steps here - https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266 however it seems a bit hacky and adds another layer of complexity. It also seems to only allow one replica (which makes sense as the disk can't be mounted multiple times) so if/when the pod goes down, my persistent storage will as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's possible now with [Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/).

First create a Filestore instance.

```sh
gcloud filestore instances create nfs-server
    --project=[PROJECT_ID]
    --zone=us-central1-c
    --tier=STANDARD
    --file-share=name="vol1",capacity=1TB
    --network=name="default",reserved-ip-range="10.0.0.0/29"
```

Then create a persistent volume in GKE.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: fileserver
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1T
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /vol1
    server: [IP_ADDRESS]
```

[IP_ADDRESS] is available in filestore instance details.

You can now request a persistent volume claim.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: fileserver-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: "fileserver"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100G
```

Finally, mount the volume in your pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my container
    image: nginx:latest
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /workdir
      name: mypvc
  volumes:
  - name: mypvc
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: fileserver-claim
      readOnly: false
```

Solution is detailed here : https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares

Comment: I am no longer working with GKE but did do a successful test while I was. That said,  I am not the biggest fan of this NFS approach especially because you have to create the persistent volume with an IP address. I believe the challenge I had was with scripting this out for n number of environments. Do you have an example of how you achieved that?

Comment: You could perform an automatic script deployment with terraform : you could create filestore instance with it :https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/filestore_instance.html. Then provision GKE cluster https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html. And provision kubernetes objects with terraform :https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html. With terraform you can use filestore instance information (like ip) to kubernetes automatically.

Comment: Good point. Will be starting to use Terraform on a new project with AWS which seems to be the right decision.

Comment: Is it possible to "split" the 1TB filestore for use in different clusters or deployments ? I noticed that on pvc you request storage of 100GB . What is this going to do exactly? Create a share under  [IP_ADDRESS]/vol1/share1 of 100GB ? Can I create another pvc of 200GB in order to mount it in another deployment under [IP_ADDRESS]/vol1/share2 ? thanks

Comment: There is an error in your PersistentVolumeClaim description, if should be this in order to work storageClassName: "" and volumeName: "fileserver"

Comment: It might be relevant to note the pricing on this https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/service-tiers. Since it starts at $204 for a HDD and $758 for an SDD people (like me) can consider it an absolute no-go due to the pricing.

Comment: Since edit que is full, writing it here.
```storageClassName: ""``` and  ```volumeName: fileserver``` with the same indent level is also works, just like the linked solution detail

Comment: @leeman24 for that matter AWS also does not allow ReadWriteMany on EBS, nor does Azure on their equivalent. How did you solve it then?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are using Terraform already to manage your GKE, you can also use [this](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/DeimosCloud/nfs/google/latest) terraform module to handle "nfs-server" creation & management for you.

Personally, I found this very handy in my situation as it's cost-effective and I don't have to manually create the "nfs-server".