# NFS or other ReadWriteMany volumes for GKE AutoPilot

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nfs

The only option I could find for rwmany on GKE is NFS, and I went with this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/readwritemany-persistent-volumes-in-google-kubernetes-engine-a0b93e203180

The only problem is that it contains the spec

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nfs-server
          image: k8s.gcr.io/volume-nfs:0.8
          ports:
            - name: nfs
              containerPort: 2049
            - name: mountd
              containerPort: 20048
            - name: rpcbind
              containerPort: 111
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
```

The problem being `privileged: true`. This is not allowed on AutoPilot. Any ideas how to get around this limitation?

Comment: Perhaps check [filestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54796639/how-do-i-create-a-persistent-volume-claim-with-readwritemany-in-gke)

Comment: I agree  - filestore is a good option here.  If you want dynamic provisioning, you can use the Filestore CSI driver:  https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-filestore-csi-driver

Comment: doesn't filestore start at 1TB? That's way too much for us

Answer (score 0):

As I see in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#no_privileged_pods) Privileged containers are not permitted in Autopilot and that's probably why the NFS server didn't work.

My recomendations are

1. Use a Standar Cluster
2. Have the NFS server outside the cluster as in a normal VM
3. Use a managed service like [Filestore](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/nfs-cloud-file-storage-on-google-cloud)

Comment: 2. is what I went with. It seems like an ugly hack though, and I hoped there might be a better solution